# Legendre's original text on elliptic functions

Tags: mathematics, legendre

Raymond Ayoub quoted Legendre in his paper on the early history of elliptic functions(*The Lemniscate and Fagnano's Contributions to Elliptic Integrals,1984*):

> ...*lucky events which do not arise except to those who know how to give them birth.*

G. N. Watson also referred to a similar text in his paper "The Marquis and the Land-agent; a Tale of the Eighteenth Century":

> *...as Legendre once remarked in another connection, occur only to those who know how to produce them.*

**Question:** What is Legendre's original text of these quotations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Euler par une combinaison qu'on peut regarder comme fort heureuse,
>   quoique  ces hazards n'arrivent qu'à ceux qui savent les faire naître,
>   trouva cette integrale...

Adrien Marie Legendre, *Traité des fonctions elliptiques et des intégrales eulériennes: (1825) Théorie des fonctions elliptiques et son application à différens problèmes de géométrie et de mécanique*, Imprimerie de Huzard-Courcier, page 2 (easily found in google books)

Comment: Wonderful answer. I really appreciate it.